# Web Service with Windows Authentication with Soap Client

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I need to access a webservice from a c# forms app.

The webservice needs Windows Authentication.

I use the following code:

```
ServiceDeskSoapClient sd = new ServiceDeskSoapClient();
sd.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = @"mydomain\myusername";
sd.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "mypassword";
sd.MyMethod();
```

But get the following error:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.
```

How do I correctly set the credentials so it uses windows auth, not anonymous?

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone still needs this, I had the pleasure of figuring it out today. It really was quite simple:

```
var server = new MySoapClient();
if (server.ClientCredentials != null)
{
    server.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;
    server.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("MyUsername", "MyPassword", "MyDomain");
}
```

Comment: It seems that AllowNtlm is deprecated, and that it uses the computers setting, do you know how to enable NTLM in windows 7 ?

Comment: I received the same depreciation warning. I was able to get it working, following this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732391.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Add the following inside the <binding> section in the client's app.config:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
  <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

(from http://morrisbahrami.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/http-request-is-unauthorized-with.html)