# passing username and password to soap webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am working on a soap webservice in c#. It look like this:

```
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

public MyService()
{
}

[WebMethod]
public string Hello()
{

    return "hello";
}
}
```

and I added a service reference to this web service from another website, so I can access the `Hello()` method from there using the code:

```
MyServiceSoapClient client = new MyServiceSoapClient();
client.Hello();
```

Now I need to pass the credentials to that web service. I have tried:

```
MyServiceSoapClient client = new MyServiceSoapClient();
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pwd";
    client.Hello();
```

But I could not manage to get these credentials in the webservice ( in the `Hello()` method).

How can I get these values in the webservice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862941/web-service-with-windows-authentication-with-soap-client

Answer (score 1):

You get the user via the [WebService.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.user.aspx) property. This will give you the username but there is no way to retrieve the passed password, this is by design as the authentication happens at the IIS level before your WebService is run.

```
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public MyService()
    {
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "hello, my name is " + User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. while using User.Identity.Name, i am getting the windows username.not the one i had set from the client

Comment: Read the page on the MSDN for the documentation, you may need to set the authentiaction type up.

Comment: The other one to check is `Context.Session.User.Identity` I do not know if that is the same user as `User.Identity` or not.