# Windows Authentication in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-express, iis-8

I have 2 web services A and B hosted under the same web site. Web Service A uses/calls the APIs of web service B.
Both the services are using the "Custom Application pool" as they need to access Database...and I need to use Windows Authentication for both the services.

So when I try to call the API of service A, it prompts me for userName and password and after that it throws an error.
Now if I change the authentication of web service B to anonymous, it works fine.
It seems to be double-hop issue but I am not sure how to fix it..

Please help me in fixing this issue..

Thanks

Comment: I think it is a question for serverfault.com and not for SO.

Comment: I think when ServiceA calls to serviceB, on server, it creates a new connection, and identify that connection by the user on the application pool, (default: `IIS_IUSER`). As a work around, in your serviceA code wich needs to call serviceB, after initialize the type, set a default client credentials, using the authenticacion already made on serviceA. Check teh4x answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862941/web-service-with-windows-authentication-with-soap-client

Comment: I cannot hard code the credentials in my code, as anyone in the same domain can access the web service A.