# Passthrough Windows credentials to IIS web app from Outlook add-in

Tags: iis, outlook, add-in

We are currently thinking about idea of Outlook add-in to call our web service (neither EWS nor Outlook REST API). The main question is - is it possible to pass user credentials to IIS server that hosts web service protected  with Windows authentication?   We are using  Outlook with Exchange, yes.

Comment: Do you develop a COM or web add-in for Outlook?

Comment: COM. We are not developing yet, just thinkig about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider your VSTO based add-in as a regular .net application. Every option that are available in the .net world is possible with the add-in. Take a look at the following pages for choosing the best solution:

- [HOW TO: Pass Current Credentials to an ASP.NET Web Service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813834/how-to-pass-current-credentials-to-an-asp-net-web-service)
- [Web Service with Windows Authentication with Soap Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862941/web-service-with-windows-authentication-with-soap-client)